# MySQL DateTime incrase by 1 minute with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to have DATETIME records on MySQL database increased by 1 minute In a sequential manner to end with something like:

```
2018-02-08 00:00:00
2018-02-08 00:01:00
2018-02-08 00:02:00
2018-02-08 00:03:00
```

tried to update records by doing this:

```
$minutes = 0;

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $minutes++;
        $newtimestamp = strtotime('2018-02-18 00:00 + '.$minutes.' minute');
        $updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newtimestamp);
    }
```

But, it's not working and I get same time for each records on MySQL.

Comment: Where are you saving records?

Comment: look at the edit

Comment: When it's about Date/Time, I always prefer [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

Comment: Well you're overriding `$updated` with every iteration and since there is no db update in your code snippet, I assume that you do the update only after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects to achieve this:

```
$records = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$start_time = new DateTime('2018-02-18');

foreach ($records as $record)
{
  $start_time->add(new DateInterval('PT1M')); // Add 1 minute
  echo $start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Output:

```
2018-02-18 00:01:00
2018-02-18 00:02:00
2018-02-18 00:03:00
2018-02-18 00:04:00
2018-02-18 00:05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
$tableresults = array('2018-02-08 00:00:00','2018-02-08 00:00:00','2018-02-08 00:00:00','2018-02-08 00:00:00');

$i=1;

foreach($tableresults as $DateTime){
        $DateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime));
        echo $cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$i.' minutes',strtotime($DateTime)));
    $i++;
}
```